# "swapfiles" taking 45 GB space on Mac... What's the fix?

Tags: mac, memory, ssd

[image: DaisyDisk screenshot]

My Mac's SSD is filling up and I figured its because of these files. Can I delete them ? What to do here?

Comment: Could you go to these folders and list the subfolders by size?

Answer (score 0):

You should not blindly delete them. `/var` is just a link to `/private/var`. A typical thing that takes a lot of space there is temporary files in `/private/var/tmp` and `/private/tmp`. You can safely delete those after closing all programs and rebooting.